# Class variables resetting in python

Tags: python, class, while-loop, pygame, reset

Right now I am having a problem where a class' values are being reset I am not sure where. can anyone help? Here is the code

```
while True:
   #some code#
   Hub().paint(gameDisplay)
```

The Hub/paint function is shown below

```
def paint(self, screen):
    if self.gimseen == 0 and self.pressed == 0:
        screen.blit(image1, (self.x, self.y))
        self.pressed = (pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0])
        if self.pressed == 1:
            self.gimseen += 1
```

in some code I call a function that i also use to get the value of self.pressed is there any other way I could do this besides adding a line above the while loop that states that hub = hub()?

Comment: Your creating a new instance of `Hub()` each time you loop. You need to create **_one_** instance of hub **_outside_** of the loop, and then call the method `paint()` **_inside_** of the loop on the **_one_** instance of `Hub()`.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that? Thanks for all your help

Comment: Sure, I just left an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your variables are resetting, is because you create a brand new instance of the `Hub()` each time your while loop loops. This means that each time you call `paint()`, any state you had with the previous instance of `Hub()` is lost. Instead, you need to create one instance of the `Hub()` class outside of the while loop, and then call the method `paint()` inside of the loop on the one instance of `Hub()`:

```
# only create one instance of hub.
hub = Hub()
# create you loop.
while True:
    # call the method paint on the
    # the one instance of Hub(); hub.
    hub.paint()
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help but the value for hub.pressed is derived from a function I call above in some code and as a result the value of hub.pressed starts of as being 1 when I need it to start off as being 0 is there anything you could think of that could solve this problem? if there is any other code or information you need I can get it to you.

Comment: @ChrisHowe I'm sorry, but I cannot help you here. Comments are not a good place for solving bug issues. Your welcome to ask another question. But please take our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read with is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).